# Compare two array's and disable element if the id's are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two array in the state and both have id's.

```
arrOne = [2,6,8]
arrTwo = [3, 8, 4]
```

if some array have the same value (In this case 8) i would like to disable all the buttons that have this equal value.

I tried like this but i'm not getting it

```
button = () => {
const checkId = this.state.arrOne.filter(arr => arr.includes(this.state.arrTwo.map(data => data.id))


if(checkedId){
return <Button disable />
} 

return <Button />
}
```

```
render(){
this.button()
}
```

I have buttons with all the array, if the array one is equal to the array two i want to disable this specific button that is equal
Any ideas ?

thanks for the help

Comment: `arrOne.some(n => arrTwo.includes(n))`

Comment: It's disabling all the buttons for some reason

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
const isDisabled = this.state.arrOne.some(item => this.state.arrTwo.includes(item));

return <Button disabled={isDisabled} />;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's disabling all the buttons and not the specific button of that have this id, any ideas ???

Comment: This was not clear from the code. Can you show how do you use `button` function?

Comment: I use the this.button() inside the render method!

Thanks for the help

Comment: `i would like to disable all the buttons that have this equal value`. What do you mean by `value` and how do you distinguish buttons by this `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Find the intersection of array and do the logics

```
var setOne = [2,6,8];
var setTwo = [3, 8, 4]

var hasDuplicateValues = [...new Set(setOne)].filter(item => setTwo.includes(item));

if(hasDuplicateValues.length > 0) {
    // Disable button
}
else {
    // Enable button
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to iterate through entire array when you need to check for a single match, `Array.prototype.some()` would be faster for larger arrays (check out my comment below initial post). Removing duplicates with `...new Set()` could be another waste of performance if there's NO duplicates, which is very possible, given OP is talking about ***id's***.

Comment: With this solution it's disabling the two buttons for some reasons ??

```
console.log(hasDuplicateValues);
[8]
```

Comment: I updated the question it was not really clear, sorry about that